# Python TypeError when passing yield outputs to a pool of workers. Want to split a large file into chunks of lines

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing, generator, pool

The code below is returning a strange type error at the job.get() line:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: """ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "G:\emd\mppurger.py", line 41, in process_wrapper
    run(line)   File "G:\emd\mppurger.py", line 25, in run
    if correct(copy):   File "G:\emd\mppurger.py", line 4, in correct
    print('Not Equal to 14? ' + item) TypeError: must be str, not list """

job.get()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: must be str, not list
TypeError "string not list".

File "g:\EMD\mppurger.py", line 76, in <module>
  job.get()
File "C:\Python36\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
  raise self._value

builtins.TypeError: must be str, not list
```

The only list must be the jobs list. But this is an iterant not iterator?

My assumption is that this is referring to the arguments that I am trying to pass to process_wrapper function.

```
cores=16
pool = mp.Pool(cores)
jobs = []

#create jobjs
for chunkStart, chunkSize in chunkify("out.txt"):
    jobs.append( pool.apply_async(process_wrapper,(chunkStart, chunkSize )))

#wait for all jobs to finish
for job in jobs:
    job.get()

#clean up
pool.close()
```

My generator function that produces chunkStart chunkSize is as follows:

```
def chunkify(fname,size=1024*1024):
    fileEnd = os.path.getsize(fname)
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        chunkEnd = f.tell()
        while True:
            chunkStart = chunkEnd
            f.seek(chunkStart + size, 0)
            f.readline()
            chunkEnd = f.tell()
            chunkSize = chunkEnd-chunkStart
            yield chunkStart, chunkSize
            if chunkEnd > fileEnd:
                break
```

Comment: When asking about code that produces an exception, please include the complete Traceback (formatted as code) in your question.

Comment: Have you tested `chunkify()` - does it work?

Comment: works like a dream... :) my chunkification isn't the problem

Comment: It is something to do with the get() clause. see traceback above thank you.

Comment: Just realised wing-ide wasn't giving me the full traceback... it's rubbish!!!

Comment: The error is here: `print('Not Equal to 14? ' + item)`.

Comment: Is G:\emd\mppurger.py your program? That's where the error is.

Comment: what sort of hellish dreamscape do you inhabit? (smile) You should open the file in `rb` mode. `seek/tell` aren't accurate otherwise.

Comment: @tdelaney my dreamscape is indeed hellish. if you only knew.....:-)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume this was an indentation error or something. I couldn't find the error but upon re-writing the code, it disappeared.